# Liferay: How to read Subfolders from DLFolder per API?

Tags: api, file-io, liferay

How to read Subfolders from DLFolder? In API I haven't found method like

```
class DLFolder { 
...
public Set<DLFolder> getChildren(){
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolders(long groupId, long parentFolderId);
```

So if you have DLFolder object that is parent folder get it's id end use it as parentFolderId. You will get List of children DLFolder items.